# Python Selenium: Click a href="javascript:()"

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I am using chromedriver and I have the following webpage source:

```
<form id="stepLinksForm" name="stepLinksForm" method="POST" target="mainFrame"> 

  <ul> 
      <li> <a href="javascript:submitLink('action_one.htm')">Action One</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="javascript:submitLink('action_two.htm')">Action Two</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="javascript:submitLink('action_three.htm')">Action Three</a> </li>
  </ul>   

</form>
```

After clicking anyone of the href, the browser goes to a new page but the url stays the same.
What I want to achieve is clicking the first href, i.e. 
`<li> <a href="javascript:submitLink('action_one.htm')">Action One</a> </li>`

I have tried find_element_by_xpath, link_text and some other methods suggested on the Internet but none of them works.
I really appreciate if someone could help.

Comment: does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24312979/selenium-and-clicking-an-a-with-href-javascript

Answer (score 5):

Instead of click you can call the javascript code directly:

```
browser.execute_script("submitLink('action_one.htm')")
```

which equivalent to javascript:submitLink('action_one.htm')

Or you can find the a by its text:

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Action One')]")
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried the first method but returns "WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: submitLink is not defined". I tried the second one before with .click() but it returns 'list' object has no attribute 'click' and I print what is found it reutrn an empty list [].

Comment: That's look like your page is render with javascript and or it live inside a container (iframe). Please try to wait for content render (sleep) before execute code. Also try to view source of the page (not dev tool view source)

Comment: a live url to your page also help

Comment: I put a time.sleep but still nothing changed. I cannot see the web source I want by "View Page Source" but I see them by "Inspect". Does this imply anything? And how can a live url helps? Thanks.

Comment: Inspect will see rendered html (may result from javascript renderer)
give url so we can help you select correct data

Answer (score 3):

To click on the first href with text as **Action One** you can use either of the following options (*Python Language Binding Art*) :

- `linkText` :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_link_text("Action One").click()
  ```
- `cssSelector` :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href*='action_one.htm']").click()
  ```
- `xpath` :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'action_one.htm') and contains(.,'Action One')]").click()
  ```

---

### Update

As you are unable to locate the element through `LINK_TEXT`, `CSS`, `XPATH` and even after `time.sleep()` it is pretty much confirmed that the element is within an **frame** which is denoted by the **`<frame>`** tag.

Now as you are able to *see them by "Inspect"*, locate the element within the *HTML DOM* and traverse up the *HTML*. At some point you will find a `<frame>` tag. Grab the attributes of the `<frame>` tag and *switch* to the intended *frame* first and then try to use the *Locator Strategies* provided in my answer. Here you can find a detailed discussion on [**How can I select a html element no matter what frame it is in in selenium?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770144/how-can-i-select-a-html-element-no-matter-what-frame-it-is-in-in-selenium/47771879#47771879)

Comment: None of these works with error: unable to locate element.

Comment: @kelvin Check out my answer update and let me know the status.